# Condition to identify the feature is available or not

Tags: wix

I have two features in my installer. I need to show a special dialog only for Feature1

I used this condition `<![CDATA[&Feature1=3]]>` so it works for first time installation. Now if i run this installer for second time, i need to check whether Feature1 has Checked on or not. (even if it already installed)

I tried `Installed AND <![CDATA[&Feature1=3]]>` this works when first time Feature1 has not installed.

Lets say if i run this installer as follows. I need to true the condition (Show the dialog) for both time.

**First installation:**

[image: First installation:]

**Second time installation (for change)**

[image]

Can anyone help me to put a condition for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using, and looking for further [Feature and Component State Values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368012#Feature_and_Component_State_Values), but I'm unclear exactly what behavior you desire. [Examples of Conditional Statement Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368561) includes the following example:

> **Run action only if the product will be installed local. Do not run action on a reinstallation.**
>
> ```
> (&FeatureName=3) AND NOT(!FeatureName=3)
> ```
>
> <sup>The term "&FeatureName=3" means the action is to install the feature local. The term "NOT(!FeatureName=3)" means the feature is not installed local.</sup>

It sounds like you may wish to tweak this by removing the NOT, and changing the AND to OR. If you do so, the result would be a condition that is true whenever the feature is already installed or is about to be installed.

Alternately, you may wish to exclude the scenario when the feature is about to be removed. If so, you could craft it similarly to this:

```
(&Feature1=3 OR !Feature1=3) AND NOT(&Feature1=2)
```

This is true if the feature is about to be or is already installed, unless the feature is about to be removed.

---

<sup>As a side point, I would suggest either putting the `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>` around your entire condition, or excluding it entirely. I find your example of `Installed AND <![CDATA[&Feature1=3]]>` to be harder to read than either the fully-wrapped`<![CDATA[Installed AND &Feature1=3]]>` or the entity-escaped `Installed AND &amp;Feature1=3`.</sup>

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. And thank you for your side point too.